# 'find /Users …' works, but 'find . …' and 'find ~ …' do not. Why?

Tags: bash, find

I can't figure out why the first two don't work and the third runs.  The interrupt was after waiting a bit for the error message.  I've used the first two patterns successfully before, differing only in the search string.

```
MBP-WWG:RJG WGroleau$ find . -type f -exec grep -il Durango "{}" \; grep -v Library
find: grep: unknown primary or operator
MBP-WWG:RJG WGroleau$ find ~ -type f -exec grep -il Durango "{}" \; grep -v Library
find: grep: unknown primary or operator
MBP-WWG:RJG WGroleau$ find /Users -type f -exec grep -il Durango "{}" \; > /tmp/tmp
^C
```

`which find` returns `/usr/bin/find` (MacOS)

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -type f -exec grep -il Durango "{}" \; grep -v Library
#                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You've got a second `grep` command hanging out causing trouble. Perhaps you meant to pipe the results of the first one to the second?

```
find . -type f -exec grep -il Durango "{}" \; | grep -v Library
#                                             ^
```

FWIW, GNU `grep` can search recursively with `-R`/`-r`. No need to use `find`.

```
grep -Ril Durango . | grep -v Library
```

Answer (score 0):

btw, you can replace

```
find . -type f -exec grep -il Durango "{}" \;
```

by

```
grep -rs -il Durango .
```

`-r` means recurse and `-s` silent. See `man grep` for details. It works, because you will find all files.

So the final command will be:

```
grep -rs -il Durango . | grep -v Library
```

Comment: I don't understand why you've added `-s`. What error-message are you trying to suppress? By the way, one difference between your command and the OP's is that `grep -r` will follow symlinks, whereas `find` doesn't (unless you specify the `-L` option). That may or may not make a difference in the OP's case.